# Visual Studio 2010 changes files to wrong encoding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encoding, character-encoding

I've been annoyed by this for a long time now. Somehow Visual Studio 2010 (VS2008 too IIRC) changes the encoding of my files from "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" to "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252".

I have a faint idea that it's either ReSharper or VisualSVN, that's doing the character encoding changes, but I have not been able to find any real proof.

It seems to happen at no specific point (seemingly random), which is quite a problem, when I am doing web-development, as the changes makes the pages display strange characters  >:(

Does anyone have a clue what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was apparently a problem with ReSharper 5.1 EAP versions. It is now fixed in the latest public release.